# UTF-8 charcters in RCP build

Tags: eclipse, maven, utf-8, rcp, tycho

I am facing problems when comparing UTF-8 charcters in an Eclipse RCP:

one of my classes generates a string "2 µs", then another class parses this value and checks for "µs". When I launch this RCP directly from eclipse everything works as expected and I am able to parse the value.

But when I build my product using maven, the String I'd like to parse mutates to: "2 Ã‚Âµs"

The maven build uses
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

I checked the class files within my eclipse projects and the jar created by maven: The String constant for "2 µs" uses the same hex encoding: "32 40 C2 B5 73"

There must be some difference between maven compiling my classes and eclipse doing that But I am lost here - does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: It looks like [the same problem I was facing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226878/why-do-i-need-to-escape-unicode-in-java-source-files).

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, however the solution seems strange to me: eclipse is doing everything right here when launching from within eclipse - so eclipse knows about my file encodings.
My build uses maven/tycho and I declared sourceEncodings there, so why does it fail?

Comment: Eclipse is complex and its always hard to know where it's buggy and where the features are just strange. Here the problem seems to be in Eclipse's Product Export Wizard.

Comment: Did you test it ? Did it solve the problem ?

Comment: @dystroy: I just tried running my eclipse with -Dfile.encoding=UTF8. It did not solve my problem. As I use maven (embedded, v3.0.4) for my build I am not sure whether this parameter is honored by maven

Comment: As I don't use maven I can't help you. You might get a better visibility for your question by adding the [java] tag (the [tycho] one might be useless).

Comment: Have you tried running maven from the command line (without Eclipse)?  If this project is part of a multi-module build, have all the projects been rebuilt and installed to the local artifact repo?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Tycho. If you can reproduce this problem in a new, minimal project, it would be good if you could open a bug report in [Tycho's issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho).

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your Eclipse to make your workspace UTF-8 too, like this
[image: UTF-8]

after this, your projects will be rebuilded, and this configuration `project.build.sourceEncoding` will work.

Answer (score 0):

It may worth checking if your rcp installation 
workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs has 'encoding=UTF-8'.